# Room @Query annotation string field without quotations

Tags: database, sqlite, android-room, androidx

I have a DAO method like this:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Libs where :field like :search")
fun findLib(search:String,field:String): List<Lib>
```

I want to replace **field** as is, but Room adds quotation marks to it in generated code.
For example I want to findLib("james%","author") to generate this SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM Libs where author like "james%"
```

but it generates this :

```
SELECT * FROM Libs where "author" like "james%"
```

how can I force it to not embed in quote marks?

Answer (score 1):

SQLite does not support parameters for column names as far as I know. Thus you are misusing Room. Correct use case would be this:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Libs WHERE author LIKE :search")
fun findLib(search:String): List<Lib>
```

Usage: findLib("james%")